# How can I count the records from one table and populate a record with the value dynamically

Tags: ms-access, dynamic, count, record

I am using MS Access 2007.

I am collecting data of different types of businesses within a town area, arranged by streets, the business.

In TableA, I have a list of different specific streets, no duplicates, field: Street; and another, field: NumOfBusinesses.

In TableB, I have a list of different specific businesses, Business; and what street they are on, Street.

eg

```
TableA

STREET..................NUMOFBUSINESSES

High Street
Sheep Street
Silver Street
Gold Street

TableB

BUSINESS................STREET

McD's                    High Street
Hair Dresser             High Street
Shoeshop                 Gold Street
```

What I want to be able to do, is count the amount of business per street from TableB and add that into the TableA, corresponding to each street.

I have over 600 streets, so I don't want to have to manually go through each individual count and add it in manually.

Is there a type of query I can use, or even code I could put in as the default value of the "Num...sses" field, so it dynamically changes the query depending on the relevant street in the record?

So in essence, I want TableA to look like this automatically

```
TableA

STREET..................NUMOFBUSINESSES

High Street             2
Sheep Street            0
Silver Street           0
Gold Street             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results from a query, so do you really need to update a field?

```
SELECT Tablea.Street, Count(Business) 
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN Tableb
ON TableA.Street = TableB.Street
GROUP BY Tablea.Street
```

It is not usually recommended that you store calculated data.

If you really must store the count, you can say:

```
UPDATE tablea 
SET numofbusinesses=
   DCount("*","tableb","street='" & Replace(street,"'","''") & "'")
WHERE Street Is Not Null
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so quick!! I really wasn't expecting that. I know it is against all principle to store calculated data in fields, but that is necessary for what I am trying to achieve unfortunately. I have ran a query using your method at the bottom, and I thought it was about to work, but I get the error message: "...can't update all the records in the update query. Didn't update 9 fields due to a type conversion failure."           I don't quite know what that is yet, any advice on where to go from there? Really appreciate all your efforts and time. Thanks @Remou

Comment: You can get an answer here in less than 5 minutes often enough.

Comment: Just trying to work on it again this morning, but I still get the same error message.                 "...can't update all the records in the update query. Didn't update 9 fields due to a type conversion failure."                I think it's talking about records, not the fields. Have you come across this before. Thanks again @Remou

Comment: You may have null streets (empty) in tablea, so add the where statement above and see if it works for you. BTW, the records that had streets should have updated, so the error is more in the nature of a warning.